# Is the infinite continued fraction $[0;0,0,\ldots]=0$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions

Wolfram|Alpha [states](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContinuedFractionK%5B0%2C+0%2C+%7Bk%2C+1%2C+Infinity%7D%5D) that the infinite continued fraction $$\cfrac{1}{0+\cfrac{1}{0+\cdots}}=0.$$
Assuming $[0;0,0,\ldots]$ exists implies that the continued fraction is $1$, since $x=\dfrac{1}{0+\cfrac{1}{0+\cdots}}=\dfrac{1}{x}$ implies $x=1$ (ignoring the negative value). This, along with the divide by zero error, suggests W|A is wrong.

Is this an error on W|A's part? If not, is this just a convention, and is there a similar convention for $$\cfrac{0}{0+\cfrac{0}{0+\cdots}}?$$

Comment: Did you mean to write $1$ or $0$ in the numerators?

Comment: I accidentally wrote 1 as 0 in my second equation (the equation with x); this is fixed now.

Comment: You are correct that if the expression means anything then it equals its own reciprocal so it has to be $1$ or $-1$. But I think if you go to the definition of simple continued fraction you find it doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Gerry indicates in his comment: the definition of an infinite continued fraction is the limit of its finite truncations. Here none of the truncations are well-defined, so certainly neither is the limit.